# Is the Hausdorff dimension less than the box counting dimension?

Tags: fractals, dimension-theory-analysis

I have been asked to prove that for a *bounded* set $F\subset\mathbb{R}^n$,

> $\dim_H F\le \underline{\dim}_B F \le \overline{\dim}_B F$

where $\dim_H F$ is the Hausdorff dimension, $\underline{\dim}_B F$ is the lower box counting dimension and $\overline{\dim}_B F$ is the upper box counting (Minkowski) dimension of $F$ (and I have done that).

I understand that $F$ is needed to be *bounded*, since otherwise we cannot really count the box-covering for $F$.

Now [here](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/05/19/245c-notes-5-hausdorff-dimension-optional/) I found a definition for unbounded sets $F \subset \mathbb{R}^n$:

> $\underline{\dim}_B F=\sup_{E \subset F, \rm ~bounded} \underline{\dim}_B E$
>
> $\overline{\dim}_B F=\sup_{E \subset F,\rm ~bounded} \overline{\dim}_B E$

But I failed to pove that $\dim_H F\le \underline{\dim}_B F \le \overline{\dim}_B F$ for any unbounded set $F \subset \mathbb{R}^n$.

Here's where I'm stuck:

> $\underline{\dim}_B F = \sup_{E \subset F, \rm ~bounded} \underline{\dim}_B E \ge \sup_{E \subset F, \rm ~ bounded} {\dim}_H E \le \sup_{E \subset F} \dim_H E = \dim_H F$

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The second to last step is actually $=$. It follows from countable stability of Hausdorff dimension, for example.

Comment: @cheapeffectivedietpills Can you explain please? I thought if I am taking supremum over a larger class, it will be bigger.

Comment: OK, just drop $\sup_{E \subset F} \mathrm{dim}_H E $ from the chain altogether. Show directly that the supremum over bounded subsets gives the Hausdorff dimension of $F$. Hint: $F$ is the union of $F\cap B(0,n)$ over $n$.

Answer (score 3):

As said in a comment, the proof of $\underline{\dim}_B F \ge \dim_H F$ for unbounded sets can proceed as 
$$\underline{\dim}_B F = \sup_{E \subset F, \rm ~bounded} \underline{\dim}_B E \ge \sup_{E \subset F, \rm ~ bounded} {\dim}_H E  =   \dim_H F$$
where the last step is based on the fact that the Hausdorff dimension is *countably stable*: 
$$
F = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty (F\cap B(0,n)) \implies \dim_H F = \sup \dim_H(F\cap B(0,n))  
$$

---

The inequality $\underline{\dim}_B F \le \overline{\dim}_B F$ for unbounded sets follows directly from the definition, since both sides are suprema taken over bounded sets, and the upper dimension is known to be larger for those.